# What type of ML or AI would predict personal traits from a DNA sequence?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

Suppose you have a large dataset of DNA sequences. Alongside each sequence, you have a portrait of the person with the DNA sequence. Other parameters include the age, gender and race of the person.

I would want to train this AI to at some point be able to predict, based on a new DNA sequence, the age, gender and race of the person, and perhaps generate a portrait.

What would something like this be called? What part of AI and ML does this concern? If I had to guess, it's both a regression and a classification problem and it's somehow related to Generative Adversarial Network.

Also, is there a difference between the "DNA sequence" and the "age, gender and race" parameters? I'm not sure because in the end you only use the DNA sequence to predict, but during training you would incorporate all four parameters.

Comment: to be precise, "age, gender and race" are features, not params

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are generally correct.

Prediction based on new dna sequence is prediction: so regression/classification.

Generating a portrait is more generally referred to as generative modeling.

The two are different tasks that learn different functional mappings/models. In prediction, your DNA sequence is an input mapping to age/gender/race, while in generative model all 4 along with portraits are used to learn the probability distribution you wish to sample from.